# Python: How to fill an array with x repeated n times?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

**I try do generate a series of x and repeat it n times:**

```
import numpy as np
​
x = [1,2,3,4]
n = [1,2,3,4]
​
data = []
​
for i,j in zip(x, n):
        data.append(np.repeat(i,j))

print(data)
```

**Out:**

```
[array([1]), array([2, 2]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([4, 4, 4, 4])]
```

**I want a "clean" array like:**

```
array([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4])
```

Thanks a lot if someone could point me to a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a simple one-liner using `np.concatenate`:

```
data = np.concatenate([np.repeat(i, j) for i, j in zip(x, n)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.concatenate` to concatenate a list of array along an axis (here the first axis).

```
data = np.concatenate(data)
```

does what you want.